# Simplifying and evaluating a square root expression involving tangent

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck on the following problem and would appreciate some help solving it:

The number $\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2}}}$ is equal to

(a) $\tan \frac{\pi}{4}$;

(b) $\tan \frac{\pi}{8}$;

(c) $\tan \frac{\pi}{12}$;

(d) none of the above.

I have tried simplifying the expression and using various tangent identities, but I have not been able to find a suitable form to use. I am wondering if it would be quicker to simplify the expression or if it would be easier to evaluate the tangent values of the given arguments.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The following tangent half-angle formula is useful here: $\frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{1+\cos{\theta}}=\tan^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Comment: @Bishop_1 FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D-1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Ctan%24&p=1), there's first [How is $\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}} = \sqrt{2}-1$?](/q/2090821), and then [What am I supposed to do here now? $\tan(\pi/8) = \sqrt{2} -1$ complex analysis](/q/850056).

Comment: Well, the expression obviously does *not* simplify to 1, so you can rule out (a).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

We have $\sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2}}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{(2-\sqrt{2})^2}{2}}=\dfrac{2-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}-1\,.$

We can thus eliminate (a).

Let $t=\tan\dfrac{\pi}{8}$ . Then by the double angle formula,
$$\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}=\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1\implies t^2-2t-1=0\,.$$
Hence $t=\sqrt{2}-1$ since $t>0$.

We can eliminate (c) by forming and solving a similar quadratic using the double angle formula and the value of $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the nested radical by rationalizing the denominator.

$$\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2}}}$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac{(2-\sqrt{2})^2}{(2+\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt{2})}}$$
$$= \frac{\left|2-\sqrt{2}\right|}{\sqrt{4-2}}$$
$$= \frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$= \sqrt{2} - 1$$

Trigonometry-wise, you should already know that:

$$\tan\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} = \frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$$
$$\tan\frac{\pi}{4} = 1$$
$$\tan\frac{\pi}{3} = \sqrt{3}$$

You probably *don't* have $\tan{\frac{\pi}{12}}$ and $\tan{\frac{\pi}{8}}$ committed to memory, though.  But notice that these angles are half of the “special” angles $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

If you don't remember the half-angle formula for $\tan$, let's derive it:

$$\tan 2x = \frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x}$$
$$= \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x} $$
$$= \frac{2(\cos x\tan x)\cos x}{\cos^2 x - (\cos x\tan x)^2} $$
$$= \frac{2\cos^2 x\tan x}{\cos^2 x - \cos^2 x\tan^2 x} $$
$$= \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x} $$

Let $t = \tan x$ and $T = \tan 2x$.  Then solving for $t$ gives:

$$T = \frac{2t}{1-t^2}$$
$$(1-t^2)T = 2t$$
$$Tt^2 + 2t - T= 0$$
$$t = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4+4T^2}}{2T}$$
$$t = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+T^2}}{T}$$

So to find $\tan\frac{\pi}{12}$, plug in $T = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

$$\tan\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}}$$
$$ = \sqrt{3}(-1 \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}})$$
$$ = -\sqrt{3} \pm 2$$

The formula gives two answers, but only the plus branch gives the positive result we expect from an angle in Quadrant 1.  So:

$$\tan{\frac{\pi}{12}} = 2 - \sqrt{3}$$

And for $\tan\frac{\pi}{8}$, plug in $T = \tan\frac{\pi}{4} = 1$.

$$\tan\frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+1}}{1}$$
$$=-1 \pm \sqrt{2}$$

Again, we need the value with a positive sign, so:

$$\tan\frac{\pi}{8} = \sqrt{2} - 1$$

So, your question now becomes:

> The number $\sqrt{2} - 1$ is equal to
>
> (a) $1$
>
> (b) $\sqrt{2} - 1$
>
> (c) $2 - \sqrt{3}$
>
> (d) none of the above.

So the answer is (b).